# HEROKU applicatio error heroku logs --tail

Tags: python, flask, heroku

im deploy an app in heroku but i always get an error:
error heroku logs --tail
https://github.com/sound33/flask-by-example
this is the repository i use

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhFaC.png)

i have try also using other repository that i found on Git Hub bit i always get 
the same error and i 
couldn't figure out why....
also i have problem to use free dyno and i couldn't find a usefull documentation

here the description of the logs from the command
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPTH.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDcxS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/09kAh.png
here you have the logs if that could help you

thanks a lot

Comment: run this on cmd to see the errors : `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: Can you put the logs as text, not as images? As a guideline, never use screenshot when you can copy/paste the code. So helpful to research ...

Answer (score 2):

We cannot know the error here. The error might be because of the library which you are using and is not listed in requirements file of heroku or some other. To know the exact error, we need to download and install heroku CLI from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

After installing we can check for error logs in command prompt

```sh
C:\Users\ajayy>heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
```

and then:

```
heroku logs -a mnc-nav-nifty50-api
```

We can see the error related to app in the log.

Hope it helps.